# Multiple events in aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I have a page with a textbox and a button.

The textbox contains a `Textbox1_TextChanged` event and the button has a `Button1_Onclick` event.

The `textbox` only fires his `textchanged event` after the user loses focus of the `textbox`. So after typing, the user presses the button but only the text `changed event` will fire and not the button event.

Is there a way to fire both events without using `AutoPostBack="false"`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
        debugger;
        var len = $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val().length;
        if (len > 0)
            $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
        else
            $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });

</script>
```